is there a way to make SUMIF with array criteria in wildcards sums only once even though the cell has all the criteria of the array?
I want to sum cells that has specific texts on them. I tried a lot of things with SUMIF(). Now I combined the SUMPRODUCT() function and I got closed to what I want. Using the functions SUMPRODUCT() and SUMIF() combined, having the texts that I want in a array and using wild cards on them I can have what I want but it doesn't work if the cell has more than one of the texts of the array, because it sums multiple times. What I want is to sum only once even though the cell has more than one of the texts of the array
I have two columns, one with the name of the product, other with the value of the product. I want to see the total sum of specific items so I used this formula in the cell C95:
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A92:A99,{"*apple*" ,"*orange*", "*banana*"},B92:B99))
The result is what I expect when the cells only have one of the criteria:

But when I have all the criteria in the same cell, it sums 3 times in this example:

The expected result in this example would be 4. I want to sum the cell if any one of the criteria is true, but I want it to sum only once even though more than one criteria is true.
What could I do in the formula to make it work like that?

More details are needed. Is the formula provided in the cell C95? Why is SUMPRODUCT being used? I couldn't reproduce this issue, since I encounter #ERROR! when using the provided formula?

@Chrimle there is nothing wrong with the formula (beside returning the wrong answer for the OP needs) it compiles just fine for me.

Yes, in the C95. SUMPRODUCT is being used because it was the only one working close to what I wanted

@AraújoFilho the problem may be that you tagged it for both Excel and Google sheets. Which one are you using? There is no guarantee that a formula that works in one will work in the other.

@ScottCraner Okay, then I must have made a mistake when converting the formula to work with my locale.

Sorry, @ScottCraner I will untag, I used Google sheets

You can use:
=SUMPRODUCT(B92:B99,REGEXMATCH(A92:A99,"(?i)\b(apple|orange|banana)\b"))

This formula sums the values in B92:B99 where the corresponding value in A92:A99 contains at least one of the words "apple", "orange" or "banana".
